# Native app friendly way to add two line breaks using markdown

Tags: react-native, mobile, markdown, native, kramdown

I am currently using Kramdown as my markdown library and need to add two line breaks without any HTML. I need this to be native app friendly.

The issue I'm having is the two standard methods for adding line breaks are not working for me (i.e. 'two blanks spaces' or '\').

Any thoughts?

Comment: How are "the two standard methods" not working for you?

Comment: @Waylan When using two sets of double spaces, the markdown parser seems to strip one out so I am only getting a single line break. When I use back slashes the slashes keep rendering on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

### 1. Use only one line break per line

Each native line break must be on a separate line. You cannot have two line breaks at the end of one line. Do this:

```
A line\\
\\
another line
```

Note that this only works for slash-based line breaks. Lines which only contain whitepsace are treated as empty lines and the surrounding lines would become two separate paragraphs, which is presumably not what you want.

### 2. Use the `html_to_native` option and raw HTML

Use Kramdown's [`html_to_native`](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/options.html#option-html-to-native) option to instruct Kramdown to convert raw HTML in your documents to Kramdown's native format. That way, you can use raw HTML `<br>` tags in your Markdown, and once ran through the parser, they will be indistinguishable from native Markdown line breaks.

Comment: so I tried your first recommendation and I'm no longer seeing slashes render on the frontend, but I'm only getting a single line break. 

I would like to look into your second option more, that seems like a good solution.

Thank you for the response!

Comment: Remember that is takes two lines breaks for a single blank line: one to end the preceding line and a second to create the blank line. From that point forward, you get get one additional blank line for each line break. So if you want two blank lines, then you need three line breaks. Sorry if this is not the issue, but without an example in your question, it is hard to guess what you actually are doing.